# 'ascii' codec can't encode character at position * ord not in range(128)

Tags: python, unicode, decode, encode

There are a few threads on stackoverflow, but i couldn't find a valid solution to the problem as a whole.

I have collected huge sums of textual data from the urllib read function and stored the same in pickle files.

Now I want to write this data to a file.
While writing i'm getting errors similar to -

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)
```

and a lot of data is being lost.

I suppose the data off the urllib read is byte data

I've tried

```
   1. text=text.decode('ascii','ignore')
   2. s=filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, s)
   3. text=u''+text
      text=text.decode().encode('utf-8')
```

but still im ending up with similar errors.
Can somebody point out a proper solution.
And also would codecs strip work.
I have no issues if the conflict bytes are not written to the file as a string hence the loss is accepted.

Comment: Can you show what’s in `text`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it through `smart_str` of `Django` module. Just try this:

```
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str, smart_unicode

text = u'\u2019'
print smart_str(text)
```

You can install Django by starting a command shell with administrator privileges and run this command:

```
pip install Django
```

Comment: The results are strikingly similar to the encode('ascii','ignore')

Comment: Two years down the line I can say how important this answer is for python2.7, sorry for the inconsiderate remark above^

Answer (score 9):

Your data is *unicode* data. To write that to a file, use `.encode()`:

```
text = text.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

but that would remove anything that isn't ASCII. Perhaps you wanted to encode to a more suitable encoding, like UTF-8, instead?

You may want to read up on Python and Unicode:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder

Comment: And perhaps also [Say Hello to Unicode](http://kos.gd/2013/02/say-hello-to-unicode/) (shameless plug :-))

Comment: @martijn-pieters I noticed that while writing to the db i used the encode function. and i was unnecessarily doing the encode decode while dumping the contents to a text file again.
There are however a few errors, maybe because of utf 8 and utf 16 conflicts. any resolution you might suggest ?

Comment: @martjin-pieters - Any idea on what i should do if the error still persists ?

Comment: @minocha: read the linked articles carefully, and the documentation for whatever database you are using. Perhaps the database handles Unicode natively, for example.